# swap space when installing phusion passenger

Tags: phusion-passenger, ruby

I tried to install Phusion Passenger and since I had less than 1GB free memory it recommended temporarily adding swap space with there commands:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap bs=1M count=1024
sudo mkswap /swap
sudo swapon /swap
```

Passenger installed successfully so do I now have to disable that swap space - how? It didn't say anything about reverting but I think it should because it said "temporarily add swap space". How do I negate this effect now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's up to you whether you want to disable it or not.  If you do nothing else, it'll be gone if/when you reboot.  If you want it permanent, you'll have to add it to /etc/fstab.  If you do want to disable it:

```
sudo swapoff /swap
```

Comment: In either case, you can and should reclaim the disk space with `rm /swap` once the swap is disabled (by reboot or swapoff).